Can two irrational numbers satisfy these conditions?
Consider two irrational real numbers $P$ and $Q$, which satisfy the following conditions:
$
(P+P^{-1})(Q+Q^{-1})=\text{rational}
$
$
\frac{(P+P^{-1})}{(Q+Q^{-1})}, \quad PQ, \quad P-Q = \text{irrational}
$
Can $P$ and $Q$ exist? If yes, then what are they? If no, then why?

If $P-Q$ is irrational, then so must $Q-P=-(P-Q)$, obviously. So, $Q-P$ could be omitted from the conditions.

I would look at something like:  $P$ the greater root of $x+\frac 1x=\pi$ and $Q$ the greater root of $x+\frac 1x = \frac 7{\pi}$ (the $7$ because I assume you want $P,Q\in \mathbb R$).  the fact that $\pi$ is transcendental rules out any of the other three expressions being rational (I think, I didn't write it out carefully).

@lulu, Your specified value of $Q$ is not a real number. It must be a real irrational number.

@fleablood  I had a typo in the first version of my comment.  I typed $\frac 1{\pi}$ for $Q$ where I meant $\frac 7{\pi}$...you need a value $>2$ to get a real number, hence the $7$.    Though i did refer to $7$ in the first version.  Anyway, it should be correct now.

@fleablood, Because $Q=x = \frac{π}{2} + \frac{i \sqrt{28 - π^2}}{2}$. It contains $i$, so $Q$ is not real.

@Mr.Dev  Note that you don't specify that $P,Q$ are real in your post.  That said, I figured that's what you meant and my (edited) comment should give you a simple, real example.

When we say irrational numbers, it obviously means we are talking about real numbers.

@Mr.Dev  If $\alpha≥2$ then $x+\frac 1x=\alpha$ has real solutions.  $\frac 7{\pi}>2$.  The larger real solution is $Q=\frac {7+\sqrt {49-4\pi^2}}{2\pi}$

There is no "obviously" about it.  Irrational just means not rational.  If you want real, you should specify it.  In any case, my example is real.

"It is. All irrational numbers are real numbers. " I doubt that is universally agreed on.  I've never heard anyone claim $\pi i$ was rational.

@fleablood, Understood.

I think lulus suggestion can be written up as an answer.  One can specifically calculate the values easily. As they say, so long as $\alpha > 2$ is transcendental and $\frac k{\alpha} > 2$ for a rational $k$ then the solutions to $P + \frac 1P = \alpha$ and $Q+\frac 1Q= \frac k{\alpha}$ will work.

" Even by taking the real value of Q, the result of the first condition is coming an irrational number."  You think $7$ is irrational?  We have $P + P^{-1} = \pi$ and $Q + Q^{-1} =\frac 7\pi$ so the product is $7$.

@fleablood, Understood. That's awesome!

Take $$P= \frac12 \left(1 + 3 \sqrt2 + \sqrt{15 + 6 \sqrt2}\right)$$
And
$$Q=\frac12 \left(-1 + 3 \sqrt2 - \sqrt{15 - 6 \sqrt2}\right)$$
The values of your expressions are, in order,
$$17$$
$$\frac{19+6\sqrt2}{17}$$
$$\frac14 \left(17 - 3 \sqrt{17}+ \sqrt{6 (71 - 17 \sqrt{17}})\right)$$
$$\frac12 \left(\sqrt{15 - 6\sqrt2} + \sqrt{15 + 6 \sqrt2} + 2\right)$$
It's easy to see the first value is rational while the second is irrational. To see why the other ones are irrational, they are roots to the following polynomials, respectively :
$$x^4 - 17 x^3 + 36 x^2 - 17 x + 1$$
And
$$x^4 - 4 x^3 - 9 x^2 + 26 x + 4$$
And neither of them has rational roots, by the rational root theorem. Hence, $P$ and $Q$ do exist.
